# Не прав или неправ?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

В этом-то и вопрос: слитно или раздельно пишется "(не)прав"?

Comment: Наверное, возможны оба варианта, в зависимости от контекста.

Comment: Вот! Мне интересно, в каком случае пишется слитно, а в каком - раздельно.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

В зависимости от смысла НЕ с краткими прилагательными, как и с полными, может писаться то слитно, то раздельно; ср.: *наша семья небогата* (примерно то же, что бедна) – *наша семья не богата* (т.е. среднего достатка); *эта девушка некрасива* (утверждается отрицательный признак) – *эта девушка не красива* (отрицается положительный признак), *адрес неизвестен* (утверждается «неизвестность») – *адрес не известен* (отрицается «известность»). Ср. также: *Невелика беда. – Не велика, казалось бы, эта дистанция для стайеров.*

**Чаще** встречается **раздельное** написание в парах: не нужен – ненужен, **не прав – неправ**, не согласен – несогласен, не способен – неспособен (*обычно в этих случаях больше чувствуется отрицание положительного признака, чем утверждение отрицательного*).
 (См. Розенталь Д.Э. и др. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ; примечание к п.8 §66 "Правописание не с именами прилагательными").

Answer (score 2):

Краткое прилагательное "не прав" пишется раздельно, так как оно не имеет полной формы,как и слова "не должен", "не рад".Оно выполняет функцию сказуемого.

Comment: Ваш ответ неправильный.

Comment: Почему же не имеет? "неправый" - нормальное слово.

Comment: Почему это неправильный?Если такая форма и есть, то она является архаичной.

Answer (score 1):

- Прощайте, милый граф!
- Но всё-таки, я прав или не прав? 
  В этом случае только раздельное написание. К сожалению, Грамота.ру предлагает писать "неправ".

А. Пояснение:

Из толкового словаря:
ПРАВЫЙ 
1. Справедливый, содержащий правду . Наше дело правое. П.  суд. 
2. Невиновный; не  нарушивший каких-н. норм, закона. Суд признал его правым.  Разберись, кто прав,  кто виноват. 
3. кратк. ф.  Не сделавший ошибки, правильно  думающий, говорящий, поступающий. Вы совершенно правы.

Б. В нашем случае это именно краткая форма: прав - не прав

В.Еще интересно: "Неправ твой, о Небо, святой приговор!" Здесь слитное написание (неправый = несправедливый), но часто пишут раздельно.

Г. Информация из  Интернета Я, редактор, пишу и исправляю написанное в редактируемом мною тексте: не прав. Так было во всех Словарях трудностей, по которым я работала и работаю.

Comment: Итак, раздельно. А может быть, всё-таки слитно? У этой версии тоже есть сильный аргумент. Сравним: я не прав/я был не прав. Выглядит не очень симпатично. Тогда: я неправ/я был неправ. Но слитное написание предполагает наличие слова "неправ" в толковом словаре, так как нет слова "неправый" с этим значением.

Answer (score 0):

Если слово с приставкой не- можно заменить синонимом без не-, то пишется слитно.