# "Недоступен" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, cслитно-раздельно

При невозможности загрузки очередной страницы компьютер выдал мне "Сервис временно не доступен". "Не" было написано раздельно. Но что-то меня терзают смутные сомнения. Разве это правильно?

Comment: Переведите с английского языка на русский язык следующие предложения:

1) "The service is not available temporarily.",

2) "The service is unavailable temporarily.".

Догадайтесь, что "The service is not available temporarily." <=> "The service is unavailable temporarily.".

Comment: Перевод: Сервис не есть доступен временно. Сервис есть недоступен временно. Я могу написать: сервис не доступен или сервис недоступен, просто второй вариант предпочтительнее. А вот вариант "сервис временно не доступен" нехорош. Получается пара: (сервис временно) доступен - (сервис временно) не доступен. Но мы же не это хотим сказать. Мы хотим сказать: Сервис доступен - сервис временно недоступен.Русский язык - это не английский язык, у нас свои законы, в том числе очень важен порядок слов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобный вопрос был недавно. Я бы выбрала слитное написание. Но  [Смотреть здесь.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5401/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2)

Answer (score 0):

1. Сервис недоступен. Здесь ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО писать слитно, так как две формы совпадают по значению (словообразование: доступный - недоступный - недоступен).
2. Сервис временно недоступен. Здесь ТОЛЬКО слитное написание, так как конструкция "временно не доступен" некорректна - между наречием "временно" и прилагательным "недоступен" не может находиться частица НЕ.
3. Сравнивать с вариантом "прав - неправ" сложно, так как там несколько значений слова с разными вариантами написания.

Comment: Как наречие 'временно' влияет на слитное написание?

Comment: Наречие «временно» непосредственно не может влиять на написание НЕ с прилагательным, но влияет косвенным образом, через структуру предложения. Отрицательное предложение строится по следующей схеме:  (тема) – (не) (рема).  При раздельном написании НЕ это выглядит следующим образом:  «сервер временно (пауза) (не) доступен».  (В утвердительном варианте: «сервер временно (пауза) доступен»).  Наречие «временно» относится к «теме», а  должно относиться к «реме». 
При слитном написании  мы имеем правильный вариант «сервер  (пауза) временно недоступен», где наречие относится к прилагательному.

Comment: Это выглядит достаточно логичным. Но как быть с примерами:

Сервер (не)доступен временно.

Сервер временно не работает.

А, и ещё, до кучи: где тема в следующем предложении:

>Не с гор побежали ручьи.

Comment: В русском языке относительно свободный порядок слов, и мы очень часто переставляем их, особенно не задумываясь над своими действиями. В действительности, каждый порядок слов что-то выражает. Во-первых, это тема-рема; во-вторых, при перестановке меняется  тоническое ударение, и мы можем выделить нужные нам слова. Ваши примеры: (1)Сервер ()временно недоступен.  Сервер () временно не работает.(2)Сервер недоступен () временно. В первом случае мы имеем сервер и его состояние, во втором - недоступность сервера и ее временный характер.

Comment: Не с ГОР побежали ручьи. Это предложение входит в сложную синтаксическую конструкцию, а в этом случае  тема-рема отдельных простых предложений уже не выражается. Простое предложение в виде одной фразы (с одним тоническим ударением) входит в состав сложного.

Comment: София, ну я же не просто так, абстрактно спросил (хотя про ручьи - абстрактно). У вас был тезис о том, что в отрицательном предложении  _(тема) – (не) (рема)_ слово "временно" вынужденно прилепится к теме (исказив смысл).

В предложении "Сервер временно не работает" слово "временно" относится к реме? Это предложение - отрицательное? по схеме _(тема) – (не) (рема)_? Если нет, то, получается, слитно-раздельно нельзя определять по теме-реме.

Comment: stopkran, Вы так внимательны, что мне придется объясняться дальше. Вряд ли все отрицательные предложения строятся по одному образцу. В грамматике есть понятия общего и частного отрицания, причем общее отрицание относится к глаголу, он как бы имеет особые привилегии для выражения отрицания. Поэтому глагол может самостоятельно выражать парадигму утверждение-отрицание, например: сервер работает /сервер  не работает или сервер ()временно не работает. Таким образом, частица НЕ связана только  с глаголом, и поэтому она может находиться  как в начале, так и в середине фразового отрезка (ремы).